# comma separated regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an email regex I am happy with, lets call it EMAIL.
So my field validator looks like this

```
var regex=/^EMAIL$/
```

But now the Captain tells me he wants to allow comma separated emails in the field.

What first comes to mind is something like

```
/^(EMAIL)?(, EMAIL)*$/
```

but that repeats EMAIL, which already offends my senses.  Is there a way to write this regex without repeating EMAIL?

Comment: What kind of usage has this regex? (my regards to the captain)

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean.  Its to validate an html field with javascript

Comment: But how can it be effective? Don't you want EMAIL=xxx,EMAIL=yyy?Because I don't see the interest of having EMAIL[,EMAIL]*

Comment: Its for a form representing a foobar, and the field name is "Email of person responsible for the foobar", which, it seems, could be two people with different emails, or someone who wants to list multiple emails

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This covers all the examples mentioned

```
^(EMAIL(,\s|$))+$
```

It matches

```
EMAIL
EMAIL, EMAIL
```

but not

```
EMAILEMAIL
```

Comment: huzzah! I knew it had to be doable

Answer (score 3):

Split the value by comma, then use the regex on each one.

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of a way to match email list **as it is**, without repeating EMAIL. Here is a simple workaround:

`/^(EMAIL, )+$/.test(emailList + ", ");`

Example:

```
var s = "abc, def, ghi, jkl";
/^([a-z]+, )+$/.test(s + ", ");
```

Comment: This is what I'll use for now, but my spider sense keeps telling me there is a way to express this in regex without a copy/paste

Comment: Splitting by comma (plus trimming each, if needed) and testing is also a good option, as suggested by @ck.

Answer (score 1):

Jason's seems the simplest, but for what it's worth, you could also use [backreferences](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html): `^EMAIL, EMAIL$` would be the same as `^(EMAIL), \1$`.

Comment: `\1` doesn't apply the subexpression in group #1 again, it tries to match the same thing group #1 matched the first time.  So your approach would match `me@here.com, me@here.com`, but not `me@here.com, you@there.com`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip; you probably saved me hours of confused regular expression debugging down the road. Also, Watchmen was awesome.